# Two way binding issue with ng select

Tags: angular

I am creating a multiple dropdown using ng-select plugin.My scenario is like when a user selects the items from dropdown. i need to populate the selected item object in button with close icon just below the dropdown. I can delete the selected item from both side i.e from dropdown as well as from button close icon. 
I am unable to populate the list using two way binding. Kind of new to angular world

PFB [stackblitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spb72c) .Please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the selected object from albums by filter function.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  albums = [];
  selectedMember = null;
  selectedTeamMember;
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(albums => {
      this.albums = albums;
    });
  }


  onChange(event) {
    this.selectedTeamMember = event
  }

  removeTeamMember(obj) {
    this.albums = this.albums.filter((item)=> { 
    return item !== obj
  })
  }
}
```